# what is the PHP equivalent of Javascript Number.MIN_VALUE?

Tags: php, javascript

what is the PHP equivalent of Number.MIN_VALUE?

I was able to find the PHP constants, but unable to spot PHP_INI_MIN. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php does such constant exist?

Any idea?

Here are the numbers I am getting from Javascript:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE=1.7976931348623157e+308
Number.MIN_VALUE=5e-324
```

Here are the numbers I get from PHP:

```
define("PHP_INT_MIN", -1 - ( pow(2, 8*PHP_INT_SIZE - 1) - 1) );
PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647 
PHP_INT_MIN = -2147483648
```

they do not coincide

Comment: Well, `0` is the smallest possible integer value. PHP doesn't seem to have constants for either the min or max of floating-point values. From http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php: "*The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).*"

Comment: "I know that PHP_INT_MAX is the equivalent of Javascript Number.MAX_VALUE ..." Except that it isn't.

Comment: To be clear, JavaScript's `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest positive number (not integer) that JS can represent, not the most negative value. Is that what you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is easy to calculate. Just divide 1.0 by 2.0 until reaching zero, the number right before zero equals the `Number.MIN_VALUE`. See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/yfIhdIih)

**PHP**

```
<?php
$a = 1.0;
while (1)
{
    $b = $a;
    $a /= 2.0;
    if ($a == 0.0)
        break;
}
var_dump($b);
?>
```

**Output**

```
float(4.9406564584125E-324)
```

But remember that this will give you the smallest positive number on the **server** not the **client**. If you want to interpret a number coming from client-side, you better just send `Number.MIN_VALUE` from the client to the server through a GET or POST request.